# HTML button and div appearing over navbar but using z-index breaks animations

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(30, 21, 120);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.package {
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background-color: rgb(37, 110, 194);
    padding: 40px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
p.package {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    }
div.package:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 35px 60px 0 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.purchase {
    float: right;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgb(10,27,64);
    color: white;
    border-color: rgb(24,146,40);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 17px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
.purchase:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgb(116,164,242);
    color: black;
    width: 24vw;
}
.purchase_b {
    display: none;
}
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
    top: 0;
}

.navcont {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.navcont a {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5vh 7vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
}
.navcont a:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
}
.navcont a:active {
    background-color: rgb(9,194,36);
}
#navbarIMG {
    margin: 0;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .purchase_b {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    button.purchase {
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
    p.package {
        bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 2.65vw;
    }
    .package {
        height: 70px;
    }
    .purchase:hover {
        background-color: rgb(116,164,242);
        color: black;
        width: 100%;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navcont a {
        padding: 3vh 3vw;
    }
}
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>My site</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="sticky">
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="#purchase">Purchase</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont" style="float: right;"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br class="purchase_b">
            <br class="purchase_b">
            <div class="package">
                <p class="package">Recommended Package: Standard Package | Only $20 per month!</p>
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
            </div>
            <div class="package">
                <p class="package">Popular Choice: Premium Package | Only $35 per month!</p>
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So I am currently having trouble with both the purchase box and purchase button appearing on top of the navigation bar. I tried using Z-index, however, the animations for the both the purchase box and button stopped working. Is there any way I can make the purchase box and button appear behind the nav bar? Thanks!
[image]

I have scrolled down a bit and the purchase box is going over the navbar.

Comment: can you explain your problem further please?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode As mentioned in the text above, I tried using z-index on the purchase box and button to appear behind the navbar, but when I did that, the animations for both the box and button had stopped working. The animations would not run.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand - https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/VRQKdd

Comment: @CodeBoyCode the issue is that the button is not expanding and turning light blue when the mouse hovers over it when using z-index. Is there a way to get the button to appear behind the navbar without the animations breaking? Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @CodeBoyCode position sticky doesn't seem to be working on that link.

Comment: what you want confusing question ..... i understand u want your purchase button animate  behind the nav bar when sticky nave bar comes over the button ???

Comment: position sticky is working

Comment: @Hammadtariq sorry for confusing you. What is happening is that the purchase box is going over the navbar. When I use z-index to push the purchase box behind the navbar, the animation for the purchase button stops working, it doesn't expand and turn light blue when your mouse hovers over it.

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: remove z-index from .purchase:hover  `.purchase:hover {
     z-index: 2; 
}` and gives the z-index to `.sticky {
    z-index: 1;
}` i hope it will not effect your animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `z-index:3` to `.sticky` class, have a look at below snippet.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(30, 21, 120);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.package {
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
    background-color: rgb(37, 110, 194);
    padding: 40px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
p.package {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    }
div.package:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 35px 60px 0 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.purchase {
    float: right;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgb(10,27,64);
    color: white;
    border-color: rgb(24,146,40);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 17px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
.purchase:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgb(116,164,242);
    color: black;
    width: 24vw;
}
.purchase_b {
    display: none;
}
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
    top: 0;
}

.navcont {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.navcont a {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5vh 7vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
}
.navcont a:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
}
.navcont a:active {
    background-color: rgb(9,194,36);
}
#navbarIMG {
    margin: 0;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index:3
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .purchase_b {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    button.purchase {
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
    p.package {
        bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 2.65vw;
    }
    .package {
        height: 70px;
    }
    .purchase:hover {
        background-color: rgb(116,164,242);
        color: black;
        width: 100%;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navcont a {
        padding: 3vh 3vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>My site</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="sticky">
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont"><a href="#purchase">Purchase</a></li>
                    <li class="navcont" style="float: right;"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br class="purchase_b">
            <br class="purchase_b">
            <div class="package">
                <p class="package">Recommended Package: Standard Package | Only $20 per month!</p>
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
            </div>
            <div class="package">
                <p class="package">Popular Choice: Premium Package | Only $35 per month!</p>
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <br class="purchase_b" />
                <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
            </div>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `sticky` class in the css code.

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 21, 120);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.package {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
  background-color: rgb(37, 110, 194);
  padding: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

p.package {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

div.package:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 35px 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.purchase {
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgb(10, 27, 64);
  color: white;
  border-color: rgb(24, 146, 40);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 17px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.purchase:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgb(116, 164, 242);
  color: black;
  width: 24vw;
}

.purchase_b {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  top: 0;
}

.navcont {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.navcont a {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vh 7vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

.navcont a:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

.navcont a:active {
  background-color: rgb(9, 194, 36);
}

#navbarIMG {
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .purchase_b {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  button.purchase {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  p.package {
    bottom: 100px;
    font-size: 2.65vw;
  }
  .package {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .purchase:hover {
    background-color: rgb(116, 164, 242);
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navcont a {
    padding: 3vh 3vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sticky">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navcont"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="navcont"><a href="#purchase">Purchase</a></li>
      <li class="navcont" style="float: right;"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br class="purchase_b">
  <br class="purchase_b">
  <div class="package">
    <p class="package">Recommended Package: Standard Package | Only $20 per month!</p>
    <br class="purchase_b" />
    <br class="purchase_b" />
    <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
  </div>
  <div class="package">
    <p class="package">Popular Choice: Premium Package | Only $35 per month!</p>
    <br class="purchase_b" />
    <br class="purchase_b" />
    <button value="Purchase" class="purchase" style="cursor: pointer;">Purchase</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This also works. How is it still "sticky" even though you removed position: sticky? Or is that what fixed does?

Comment: The `position: fixed` gives an absolute fixed porisition of a screen but it is still in a fixed position. The sticky position is relative.  Hope this is helpful.